# SQL Server Replication: Database does not exist

Tags: sql-server, replication

I've had a test SQL replication set up for some time now and all of the sudden I am getting:

Database 'MyDatabase' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

It is correct that 'MyDatabase' does not exist, however, I can't find the setting / property that is defining the database. 
All the properties across my publisher and subscriber look good and don't reference this database.

Comment: Did 'MyDatabase' ever exist? Is it set as the default database for the login your using?

Comment: Under SQL Server Agent, do you have any left-over Jobs or Proxies?

Comment: *What* is throwing that error? Are you running a script and getting it? Is it one of the Replication agents? "Other"? Knowing the context will go some way in diagnosing, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this happened, however, generating a new Snapshot fixed the issue.